# What's the logic behind generation of Module.symvers file?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

As far as I understood **Module.symvers** file provides list of symbols exported **by modules** plus license these are exported under and optionally a CRC. Other modules can depend on these symbols for their purposes and it's for sure logical that if my module depends on some **module X**, this **module X** should be at least built, because it **defines** symbols I need. **Module.symvers** thus serves as a sanity check mechanism, am I right?

I'm struggling to understand why some symbols that **clearly** do not depend on any modules are not being exported, e.g. I want to use `debugfs_create_u32` function. It seems to me that the only dependency that should exist is `CONFIG_DEBUG_FS`, however enabling this option exports only fraction of symbols that `#include <linux/debugfs.h>` declares. Thus every time I'm trying to compile my module I get MODPOST errors regarding undefined symbols. My workaround was to find random module that actually uses `debugfs_create_u32` symbol in it's code and compile kernel with it, this module doesn't define `debugfs_create_u32`, I do not use functionality of this module, I do not actually need it and it feels like the only useful thing this module does for me is adding line to **Module.symvers** file and everything starts to magically work.
Similar problem I've encountered with `i8253_lock` symbol, I don't need `pcspkr` module, I just want `i8253_lock`, but to get it I need to compile `pcspkr` for some reason.

I'm pretty sure that I'm missing something crucial here, that's why I'm so confused, thus I kindly ask to explain how to make sense of the above described situation, what is the logic behind generation of **Module.symvers**?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still struggling with this problem and I know it is a bit late, but I ran into the same problem tonight. And the culprit was the following option in the kernel configuration:

CONFIG_TRIM_UNUSED_KSYMS

https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/TRIM_UNUSED_KSYMS.html

If you have the option activated, just disable it.

Hope it helps.